# How do I compare two DynamicJsonObjects to check they are equal?

Tags: c#, json

I can't see how you can compare two DynamicJsobObjects. There is the method `GetDynamicMemberNames` which tells you what properties each has but how do you access the values of those properties?

I've arrived at this stub of a function but have no idea how to check the objects are the same. It stems from testing two json strings. One being a response from a web API, while the other being the expected result. I constructed the objects using `Json.Decode(expectedJsonString)` and `Json.Decode(resultJsonString)`.

Function stub:

```
public static bool AreJsonObjectsEqual(DynamicJsonObject obj1, DynamicJsonObject obj2)
{
        return // ?
}
```

How do I compare the two objects to ensure they are equal?

Comment: You could try to dynamically cast them to IDictionary<string,object> and then do your comparation.

Comment: @user629926 I think I tried something similar, but wasn't able to cast to that. I think you can do it with ExpandoObjects but I didn't have much luck with DynamicJsonObjects.

Comment: Actually depends of your DynamicJsonObject implementation .If it's one from ASP.NET helpers I thing you can cast it like ((IDictionary<string,object)(dynamic)obj1)

Comment: @user629926 Thanks, it is the one from System.Web.Helpers. I tried casting with `((IDictionary<string, object>)(dynamic)obj1)` but it threw the error `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Helpers.DynamicJsonObject' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary 2[System.String,System.Object]'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
public static bool AreJsonObjectsEqual(DynamicJsonObject obj1, DynamicJsonObject obj2)
{
    var memberNamesNotEqual = obj1.GetDynamicMemberNames().Except(obj2.GetDynamicMemberNames()).Any();
    if (!memberNamesNotEqual)
    {
       dynamic dObj1 = (dynamic)obj1;
       dynamic dObj2 = (dynamic)obj2;
       foreach (var memberName in obj1.GetDynamicMemberNames()){
           if(dObj1[memberName] != dObj2[memberName]) return false
       }
       return true
    }
    return memberNamesNotEqual;
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is great thanks, I failed in my attempts by not casting to dynamic first. I also like the simplicity in your solution.

Comment: @Ally **NOTE** if member,for example, is `List` or `Array` it can return wrong answer

Comment: Ah yes, haven't hit that problem yet but I'll have a go at working in a solution. Cheers.